# How to modify data fetched by ngResource and then return it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'd like to modify (filter) an array in an angular service (data I've got by ngResource) and then pass the modified data to controller, but I'm stuck due to it's asynchronous behaviour.

Here's the code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').factory('Report', ['Employee', function(Employee) {

    var getReports = function(employeeId) {

        return Employee.query({}, function(employees) {
            return employees.filter(function(element) {
                return employeeId === element.managerId;
            });
        });

    };

    return {
        query: function(employee) {
            return getReports(parseInt(employee.employeeId));
        }
    };

  }]);
}());
```

And I invoke it in controller like this:

```
$scope.employees = Report.query({employeeId: $routeParams.employeeId});
```

I have two issues with the above code:

1. it doesn't work :) getReports() returns whole employees array, without filtering,
2. it doesn't seem like elegant or maintainable design. What can I improve in that regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need different types on filters, you could pass a filter function as a parameter:

```
return {
    query: function(employee, filterFunction) {
        return getReports(parseInt(employee.employeeId)).filter(filterFunction);
    }
};


Report.query({employeeId: $routeParams.employeeId}, function (value) {
    // extra filtering...   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it gives me TypeError: getReports(...).then is not a function

Comment: you are correct I just noticed that you are not relying on promises.

Comment: I could but I can't really seem to get my head around promises. If you could point me to some recommendable learning resource, that would help a lot.

Comment: since you are using ngResource, to specify the custom filter function as parameter is probably the simplest approach. For a promises guide try here: http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/